# ¿Por qué no está funcionando el método stopListening()? Android Java

Tags: java, android

Veréis, tengo en mi aplicación un botón para que se pueda transcribir de voz lo que queramos decir. El problema es que he creado un contador en el botón para que cuando pulse el botón nuevamente, pare de escuchar, pero no funciona:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;
int count = 0;
SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
@BindView(R.id.etBeforeTranslate)
EditText etBeforeTranslate;
@BindView(R.id.ivLogo)
ImageView ivLogo;
@BindView(R.id.btnTranslate)
Button btnTranslate;
@BindView(R.id.btnVoice)
ImageButton btnVoice;

private DatabaseReference Translates;

public String removeAccents() {...}

public String textTranslate() {...}

public void registerTranslates() {...}

private void checkPermission() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //When permission is not granted by user, show them message why this permission is needed.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
            //Give user option to still opt-in the permissions
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);

        } else {
            // Show user dialog to grant permission to record audio
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO);
        }
    }
    //If permission is granted, then go ahead recording audio
    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        //Go ahead with recording audio now
        speechToText();
    }

}

private void speechToText() {

    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());

    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            if (matches != null) {
                etBeforeTranslate.setText(matches.get(0));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }
    });

    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);

    count = 1;

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_RECORD_AUDIO: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay!
                speechToText();
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Vaya, pues te quedas sin hablarme", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    btnVoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (count == 0) {


                checkPermission();
                speechToText();
            }

            else if (count == 1) {

                mSpeechRecognizer.stopListening();
                etBeforeTranslate.setText("holi");
            }

        }
    });

    btnTranslate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String texto = textTranslate();

            if (etBeforeTranslate.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipoangry);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "¡Ay que agobio! Intridici il tixti, anda", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Translates = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Translates");
                registerTranslates();
                ivLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.logotipo);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TranslateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("texto", texto);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        }
    });

}

}
```

El texto que metí era para comprobar que me lo mostrara para ver que se estaba realizando y efectivamente cambia, me lo muestra, es decir que entra, pero que va, no me salta el sonido como que ha parado de escuchar y ya no se si es problema de mi aplicación o de terceros, ya que leí en respuestas de hace años que no iba bien ese servicio, pero supongo que con el paso de los años se solucionó. A ver si me podéis echar una mano, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como lo mencionas, hace tiempo se tenía un "bug" en `SpeechRecognizer.stopListening()` el cual fue "solucionado", a mi parecer fue en realidad el uso incorrecto de este método.

Si en realidad si deseas terminar el servicio de reconocimiento de voz, realizalo mediante:

```
mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
```

Por cierto es buena práctica liberar recursos, realizando el mismo llamado en el método `onDestroy()` de tu `Activity`:

```
@Override
  protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //libera recursos.
    if(mSpeechRecognizer != null){
       mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
       mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
  }
```

---

> - [.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#cancel()) Termina el servicio de reconocimiento de voz.
> - [.destroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html#destroy()) Destruye el objeto SpeechRecognizer.

Comment: Efectivamente funciona. El caso es que usé el método cancel() pero sin el destroy(). Respecto al método onDestroy(), esto no es algo equivalente a usar finish()?

Comment: finish(), termina una Activity, en este caso destroy() "destruye", marca el objeto para que sea eliminado de memoria.