# Obtengo un NPE en el método onDestroy (Android Java)

Tags: java, android

A las buenas gente de bien, tengo mi siguiente método onDestroy():

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
    mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
}
```

Según la consola de Google, está causando un NPE en ocasiones, lo he comprobado y si. Yo creo que la razón es que en ocasiones estoy destruyendo un proceso que no se ha iniciado y se que la solución es con un if, pero no se como indicarle que lo destruya cuando se haya iniciado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso el problema es que en ocasiones la instancia de `SpeechRecognizer` puede ser que nunca se inicializo o estuvo activa y ahora tiene un valor null.

En este caso cuando cierras tu aplicación o `Activity` debes validar el caso en el cual `mSpeechRecognizer` tiene valor null:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(mSpeechRecognizer != null){
      mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
      mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
}
```

> no se como indicarle que lo destruya cuando se haya iniciado.

Si se ha iniciado, `mSpeechRecognizer` no tendrá valor null por lo tanto las siguientes lineas realizarán el trabajo en este caso.

```
  //Detiene.
  mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
  //Destruye.
  mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
```

[¿Por qué no está funcionando el método stopListening()? Android Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278152/por-qu%c3%a9-no-est%c3%a1-funcionando-el-m%c3%a9todo-stoplistening-android-java)

Comment: vale vale, entonces esto eran los bloqueos que estaba obteniendo desde la consola de Google. Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @Isaac que bueno que preguntaste ya que en la respuesta que respondí acerca de detener el servicio de SpeechRecognizer  es importante validar el caso en el cual no se haya iniciado el servicio, ya la edité!

Comment: si, es que me resultó extraño ya que tu mismo me diste la respuesta, y no sabía de donde podía llegar el error, ahora ya si :)